# Do any replacements for CryptoAPI exist for Windows?

Tags: c++, c, api, cryptoapi

I am having major problems with cryptoAPI, and was wondering do you get any 3rd party / better solutions for windows?

Main problem I have with CryptoAPI is that its not OS independent enough. I can't find the right balance in my code to get stuff to work on Windows 2003 and Windows 2008+.

What I essentially want to achieve can be read about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720276/how-to-use-crypto-to-extract-the-textual-information-in-a-file). This is my only use for Cryptography at this stage.

Answer (score 2):

Try Bouncy Castle, it's available in C# & Java:
http://www.bouncycastle.org/

Quite a few vendors in our space use it in production.

Comment: Looks great, do you think it can tackle this problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720276/how-to-use-crypto-to-extract-the-textual-information-in-a-file

Comment: I'm afraid I can't answer that directly.

Answer (score 2):

I could recommend OpenSSL http://www.openssl.org/. It is not only for SSL the area, but for cryptography as a whole. It is **open source code**. This fact can be very useful in some situations. It also works very will in Windows. Recommended compiled binaries and libraries for Windows you can find here http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

Comment: I tried open SSL, but couldn't find a way to decode a CMS encoded file. What I want to do is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720276/how-to-use-crypto-to-extract-the-textual-information-in-a-file, couldn't find any way yet to do this easily using openSSL, but if you know how to please share.

Comment: I am sure that you find all you needed inside the code. Download the code from http://www.openssl.org/source/ and look at example from openssl-1.0.0\demos\sign or inside openssl-1.0.0\openssl-1.0.0\crypto\pkcs7 directories. You can use a command line utility http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/openssl.html to see the possibilities of OpenSSL lirary. I recomend also look at http://www.madboa.com/geek/openssl/

Answer (score 1):

CryptoAPI is a pain to use properly, if you are having problems, can I suggest [Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/) ? The documentation isn't the best, but I've found it to be very powerful.

Without knowing more about what you are trying to achieve I can't be more help I'm afraid.

Comment: Do you think it could be used to strip a file of its certificate and just get to the text tile?

Comment: It certainly has the relevant methods, but I've mostly used it for the algorythm implementations so I can't say for sure I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

- Botan library - very nice library
- gnu-tls/libgcrypt

Answer (score 1):

Crypto++ is amazing in power, but suffers from its complexity and a lack of automation/documentation. It also suffers from a lack of debugging I think, when the check does not work, it just does not work, but you're given little hints as to what could cause the failure...

Anyway, since you are using C++, may I suggest [Google Keyczar](http://www.keyczar.org/) ?

- It's meant to be easy to use, with safe defaults, yet allows customization.
- It comes up with a complete Key Management system, which Crypto++ does not feature and which is complicated enough to code by oneself.
- It's open source too, so the code can be audited.
- It's portable even outside of the Windows environment.

I haven't, unfortunately, used it myself. I am currently stuck with Crypto++. But if I had the opportunity to choose right now, I think I'd invest time to experiment with Keyczar.